# Why does my Windows 7 always take one default route?

Tags: networking, windows-7, wireless-networking

I've been looking all around but without success.

I have a "freebox" (a box given by my ISP) and the *two* PCs use it to connect to Internet. Its IP is 192.168.1.254.

Here's my problem: I have 2 PCs: one mobile, one "fixed" PC. Both under Windows 7.

When I start my mobile PC, it says "Internet connexion problem". Ok.
When I start my fixed PC, it says "Internet connexion problem". Ok.

If I use my mobile phone as a bridge:

- When I start my mobile PC, it says "New Internet connexion" then connect to the Web. *Ok*.
- When I start my fixed PC, it says "Internet connexion problem" and *still tries to go through 192.168.1.254 to get Internet connexion*. Problem. From now on, if I physically unplug the network wire, then it uses the Wifi of my Phone to go to Internet. If I plug the network wire again, it tries again to use the 192.168.1.254 and of course, Internet don't work anymore.

What is strange is that the card configuration are the same on both my mobile and my fixed PC. I couldn't find a valuable answer on the net.

Any idea why my fixed always want to use 192.168.1.254 as soon as there's a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect your computer to a network your system obtains IP address, default gateway address and other parameters via DHCP and modifies its [routing table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table) accordingly.

You can use `route print` command to check your routing tables, that should explain what's happening. Probably, when both interfaces are up, you have two default gateway entries and the system picks the one with the lowest metric (which is not the one you want).

Your problem can be solved either by modifying the routing table directly (see `route /?` for details) or by changing interface metric using GUI, as explained [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/).

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the last link, which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the DHCP client enabled on the interface, and there are DHCP packets on the attached network cable, then there is a high chance that's what is setting the route.

You can configure the network interface to not pick up a default route, though.

Comment: So if I disable DHCP on my ISP box this is supposed to work? Then how comes I don't have the problem with my mobile, which has also both wired and wifi connexion?